# where clause not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, where-clause

when I run this

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smslogs  ");

$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
```

It's working fine. but when I run this

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smslogs WHERE ipaddress = '36.21.54.125' ");
```

above ipaddress my column name type varchar(255) in table smslogs.

It's not working even not go into below while loop

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
```

I have also tried this

```
$ip="36.21.54.125";

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * WHERE ipaddress = '". $ip . "' ");
```

but to no avail.

Can you help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by "Not Working" - throwing an error, or just returning no results?

Comment: Did you really try this query through PHP `SELECT * WHERE ipaddress = '". $ip . "'`. It is syntactically incorrect. Try building a query on the MySQL terminal first and then embed it into your code.

Comment: Sorry I am late!

@leppie, like your suggestion thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys problem resolved using the below code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `smslogs` WHERE rcpt = '$to'";

$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if( !$result )
{
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

It was a retrieval error.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smslogs WHERE TRIM(ipaddress) = '36.21.54.125' ");
```

This should work if your ipaddress fields contain additional spaces besides the actual ip address. TRIM would remove them, leaving only the data that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Either of this two codes will solve your problem. The fist code assume that ipaddress is coming from form inputs.
So I sanitized it using `mysql_real_escape_string()` function against SQL Injection Attack. While outputing the content, 
I sanitized it using `htmlentities()` against XSS attack. 
Hey wait a minute, why are you still using mysql deprecated connections, you better start using Mysqli or PDO wich 
does automatic sanitization of form input variables and ensures that SQL Injection attack is not possible.

```
<?php


$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","345") or die ("connection error");
mysql_select_db("sectona_db") or die ("database error");


?>



<?php

include("db.php");

$ip_id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ip_id"]);




$sql=mysql_query("select * from smslog where ipaddress ='$ip_id'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){


$pr=htmlentities($row['ipaddress'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");


}

echo $pr;
?>


or



<?php



include("db.php");

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smslog where ipaddress='123'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){


$pr=htmlentities($row['ipaddress'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");


}

echo $pr;


?>
```